# getCallbackTokenAsync returns an empty response with isRest(false/true)

Tags: office-js

Client: Outlook for Windows 16.25 (190512.01)

EWS: On Premise (2013)

We are using [1] getCallbackTokenAsync method with isRest set to both TRUE and FALSE , however we are are only receiving an empty response. Hence we are not able to call either the EWS SOAP API  or the REST API.

Is this a known issue when working with EWS 2013 API?

**Reference**

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/office.context.mailbox?view=office-js#getcallbacktokenasyncoptions-callback

Comment: 16.25 (190512.01) seems not a right version for Outlook Windows. Could you verify the client platform and version, is it Outlook Mac client? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

getCallbackTokenAsync required minimum mailbox set version **1.3** but Exchange 2013 on-premises only support version **1.1**

This is why you get a sucessful result but an empty value.

Comment: The add-in should not activate if the mailbox version is not supported,right?

Comment: Yes you right, if api version is not supported by your Exchange server, add-in could not be added.
Did you get back { "value": "", "status": "succeeded" } from getCallbackTockenAsync ?